# 'Absolute' container fits viewport without width/height CSS rules

Tags: html, css, absolute

I found this page: 
http://www.maddim.com/demos/spark-wp/

There is a fixed header and a div underneath that stretches to viewport without having width or height defined. It allows overflow of content in y-axis and applies scrollbar(box scroll, no viewport scrollbar) when necessary. The HTML is very simple:

```
<header> ... </header>
<div id="main" role="main"> ... </div>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 89px;
}
```

After disabling all JS and deleting majority of page elements in firebug, the bare #main element still behaves as before.

What technique was used here and where was it defined to create such behavior of the #main container?

Comment: It's pretty well spelled out in the CSS you posted. Do you not understand what those statements do?

Comment: What behavior are you talking about specifically?

Comment: What don't you understand about `position: absolute;` in conjunction with `overflow-y: scroll;`?

Comment: I overlooked the fact that you can define container's width by specifying its position(top, bottom, left and right). Now it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're some CSS basics.  `bottom: 0;` says exactly that. Stick the bottom of the element 0 pixels from the bottom of the viewport. `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` do essentially the same. `overflow-y: scroll;` says allow scrolling of content that overflows in the vertical orientation, and `position: absolute;` says take this element out of the page flow and attach it to the page in one place. `top: 89px;` gives room for the header by positioning this element 89 pixels from the top of the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it's obvious but I just didn't notice it at first. I was too busy looking for width:100%; :)